# PHPStorm "Class member access on instantiation" phpDoc

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

first note: Note that this right here is not a coding problem, it is a problem I have with the IDE PhpStorm

I have a Model class in my project that has the method `load` which basically loads something from the database. Then I have multiple classes (other models) that extend the Model, e.g.

```
User extends Model
Book extends Model
```

Now, with the in 5.4 added feature to access class membes on instantation I have some problems with the Code Inspector from phpstorm.

In the user class I have a method "getUrl()". When I call it like that

```
$user = new User();
$user->load(1);
$user->getUrl();
```

I don't get any warnings. Phpstorm knows that $user is a User object and doesn't throw a warning.

However, when I declare it like this

```
$user = (new User())->load(1);
$user->getUrl();
```

I get the warning `Method 'getUrl()' not found in class Model`. I could easily fix this by adding the `getUrl` method to the model, but there are only 3-4 classes (of 15) which use the getUrl method. Is there a way to tell him that $user is a User object and not a Model object?

I know that I could just add

/** @var User $user */

before the code, but I want this to be automatically and not that I have to regenerate this all the time.

So basically the problem is

User class has a method called getUrl
Calling that class with the class member access on instantation feature throws a warning, because PHPStorm thinks it's an object of the Model class and not of the user

Comment: Show header of `User::getUrl()`

Comment: Better -- what PHPDoc you have there for `load()` method. If it has something like `@return $this` or `@return static` .. then IDE may treat it as `Model` instead of `User` when proper class instance is created. Adding PHPDoc for `load()` in `User` class should solve it.

Comment: I tried these one for the return and the load method

`@return bool | $this | self`. But none worked

Comment: @LazyOne - Where exactly there? Would it be enough to just have the PHPDoc there or do I have to add the method as well? Because I would like not to add the method

Comment: You can re-declare `load` via PHPDoc only (without redeclaring actual method) -- just use `@method` tag in PHPDoc comment for the `User` class.

Comment: Whops, sorry for my previous comment. This still doesn't work. It still thinks the object is an instance of the class Model and not User

Comment: Please provide some test project (yes, whole test project) -- as this **simple code** works here in PhpStorm v8.0.2 EAP build: http://postimg.org/image/dyewbs15d/

Comment: Hi @LazyOne - Yes, when I have only return $this in the phpdoc it works, but the method can return either $this or bool = false, so I made it like this

return $this|bool

Only having return $this works, but adding a second return type doesn't work. If you try that out it should work. Can't send you my testproject. It is too big.

Comment: In this case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24631  (*"Can't send you my testproject. It is too big."* -- that's why it's called a "test project" -- it supposed to be small -- only necessary code that reproduces the issue)

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by adding the docblock to the `load()` method.

The problem is, that in your second example `$user` is not a result of `new User()`, but a result of `->load()` call and it looks like PHPStorm can not infer that `load` actually returns object of correct class

It should look like this:

```
<?php
class Model
{
    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return static
     */
    public function load($id)
    {
        // …
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I know that, but the problem is, that the load Method is in the model. Which means, I can't add all classes there or I would have 15 declarations at the return.

@return User | Book | Gallery etc. 

If the Method would be in the User class it would solve this problem, however it is in the Model class

Comment: @Musterknabe I added example to the answer. still doesn't work?